# Does Swagger.net works with higher .Net frameworks than 4.0

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, runtime-error, swagger

I have developed a WebAPI and trying to document it using [Swagger.Net](https://github.com/Swagger-Net/Swagger.Net). My .Net framework version is 4.5.1 where as Swagger.Net appears to be written in .Net 4.0. So its always ending up with System.Web.Http version incompatibility error (located assembly manifest definition does not match the assembly reference). Solution compiles successfully but when it opens in the browser, it errors.

Also I have tried to recompile Swagger.net source code in VS 2013 and .Net framework 4.5 but even than it ends up while requiring System.Web.Http 4.0.0.

Comment: FYI: My basic purpose to use System.Web.Http v-5.0 is that it provides attribute routing for WebAPI 2.0.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Swagger.NET MVC Api Exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21043328/swagger-net-mvc-api-exception)

Answer (score 2):

@theGeekster:  FYI, you can now use WebAPI 2.x with this fork:

https://github.com/Gcastelo/Swagger.Net

The original swagger.net project [looks dead](https://github.com/Swagger-Net/Swagger.Net/pulls).

Enjoy!

Comment: And it supports CORS as well, as you also mentioned.

Comment: I am trying to integrate the above mentioned Swagger.net upgrade in my WebAPI2. It supports CORS but when it comes to attribute routing then there are issues. I can mention e.g. [Route("api/v1//vendors")] along with [HttpGet] as Http verb but nothing works. It only appears to create /docs with config.Routes.MapHttpRoute.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think Swagger has been updated to be used along with latest versions `5.0` and `5.1` of ASP.NET Web API. Your issue could be solved by binding redirects, but I can imagine Swagger to fail with latest versions of Web API as things have changed a lot since Swagger's last release..try adding the following to your web.config.

```
  <system.webServer>
    <runtime>
      <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <dependentAssembly>
          <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Http" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
          <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.0.0.0" newVersion="5.0.0.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
```

Comment: Added the <dependentAssembly> as you suggested but it didn't solved the problem other than changing the error to this one [Method 'GetDocumentation' in type 'Swagger.Net.XmlCommentDocumentationProvider' from assembly 'Swagger.Net, Version=0.5.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' does not have an implementation.]

Comment: I think this is expected as Swagger hasn't been updated to latest versions of Web API.

Comment: Well, then I think for me you would suggest to hold on using swagger for documenting my WebAPI 2.0 until they modify the source ? Any suggestions please

Answer (score 0):

I have ended up with conclusion that using Swagger.Net, we can't use Attribute Routing (or other WebaPI2 features like native CORS support etc.)